# cloning "rows" of a form with inner functions

Tags: javascript, html, clonenode

im trying to make dynamic form with inner functions...

I have a template like:

```
``<div class="polozky row col-12" id="polozky">
                <div class="polozka row col-12 card-footer bg-yellow" id="sablona">

                  <div class="col-md-1.5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label><input type="hidden" name="policko0[]"></label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-1.5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Pořadí: <input type="number" class="inputPoradi" required name="policko1[]" tabindex="1" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $posledniVPoradi + 1; ?>" min="1"></label>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                 

                  <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Typ: </label>
                      <select class="col-md-7" name="typ[]" id="sem" tabindex="3" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
                      <option selected>Choose...</option>
                        <option value="1" <?php /* echo ($result['Typ'] == '1' ? 'selected' : '') */ ?>>Oddělení</option>
                        <option value="2" <?php /*echo ($result['Typ'] == '2' ? 'selected' : '')*/ ?>>Skupina</option>
                        <option value="3" <?php /*echo ($result['Typ'] == '3' ? 'selected' : '')*/ ?>>Položka</option>
                        <option value="4" <?php /*echo ($result['Typ'] == '4' ? 'selected' : '')*/ ?>>Vlastní sleva</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Název:</label>
                      <select class="form-select" id="Sub1" required>
                        <option selected>Choose...</option>
                        <option value="sub1">Applied Maths-1</option>
                        <option value="sub2">Applied Physics-1</option>
                        <option value="sub3">Applied Physics-2</option>

                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>





                  <button class="col-md-1 form-group btn btn-block btn-danger odebrat" onclick="odebrat(this)">× Odebrat</button>


                  <div class="col-md-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <button class="btn btn-block btn-success" type="button" onclick="pridatPole()" tabindex="1">+ Přidat</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>`
```

and the "template row" can be clone with this:

```
`<script>
  var prvniPolozka = document.getElementById('sablona');
  var sablona = prvniPolozka.cloneNode(true);
  var indexPoradi = (2 + <?php echo $posledniVPoradi; ?>);


  function indexPlusJedna() {
    indexPoradi++;
  }

  function pridatPole() {

    var kopie = sablona.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById('polozky').appendChild(kopie);
    kopie.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].focus();
    kopie.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value = indexPoradi;
    indexPlusJedna();
  }

  function odebrat(el) {
    var polozka = el.parentNode;
    polozka.parentNode.removeChild(polozka);

  }
</script>`
```

my problem is that I want to have on the every "template row" 2 select inputs... which the first one determines options what i see in the second SELECT input... the function:

```
` function dynamicdropdown(n) {
                      var arr1 = ["oddělení 1", "oddělení 2"];
                      var arr2 = ["skupina 1", "skupina 2"];
                      var arr3 = ["polozka 1", "polozka 2"];
                      var arr4 = ["sleva 1", "sleva 2"];
                      if (n === "1") {
                        document.getElementById('Sub1').innerHTML = '';
                        for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
                          document.getElementById('Sub1').innerHTML += "<option>" + arr1[i] + "</option>";

                        }
                      } else if (n === "2") {
                        document.getElementById('Sub1').innerHTML = '';
                        for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
                          document.getElementById('Sub1').innerHTML += "<option>" + arr2[i] + "</option>";
                        }
                      }
                      else if (n === "3") {
                        document.getElementById('Sub1').innerHTML = '';
                        for (var i = 0; i < arr3.length; i++) {
                          document.getElementById('Sub1').innerHTML += "<option>" + arr3[i] + "</option>";
                        }
                      } else if (n === "4") {
                        document.getElementById('Sub1').innerHTML = '';
                        for (var i = 0; i < arr4.length; i++) {
                          document.getElementById('Sub1').innerHTML += "<option>" + arr4[i] + "</option>";
                        }
                      }

                    }`
```

now it works only in the first row... I know that i cannot us getElementById and the id in html inputs... This was just used for the examle...

How to do it? Thanks for help. M.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood your question and code correctly and hope that the following might be helpful. In **most** instances ID attributes when generating dynamic content are more trouble than they are worth ( as the expression goes ) - you are better using `events` to identify DOM elements and from the `event.target` &/or `event.currentTarget` you can then use other selectors (parent,child,sibling) to further traverse the DOM.

Rather than using `inline` event handlers ( and you were having issue with one of those anyway ) you can use `delegated event listeners` bound to a parent element ( in this case the `document` itself ) and, as mentioned, use the `event` to identify the element that invoked the event. From that point the various functions for adding,cloning and deleting should be modified to work with the event.target and parentNode / childNodes.

I modified very little of the original HTML ( added new class to the buttons - `XBTN`, modified IDs to become `data-id` values and removed the PHP only for the demo. The only element that still has an `ID` is the main parent element, `id='polozky'` - everything else uses dataset attributes instead.

```js
document.addEventListener('change', e => {
  if (e.target instanceof HTMLSelectElement && e.target.dataset.id == 'sem') {
    const args = [
      ["oddělení 1", "oddělení 2"],
      ["skupina 1", "skupina 2"],
      ["polozka 1", "polozka 2"],
      ["sleva 1", "sleva 2"]
    ];
    let key = e.target.value - 1;
    let data = args[key];

    let oSelSub = e.target.closest('[data-id="sablona"]').querySelector('[data-id="Sub1"]');
        oSelSub.innerHTML = '';
        data.forEach( item=>{
          oSelSub.appendChild(new Option( item, item ));
        });
  }
});


document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement && e.target.classList.contains('XBTN')) {
    switch (e.target.dataset.id) {
      case 'odebrat': odebrat.call(this, e); break;
      case 'pridat': pridatPole.call(this, e); break;
    }
  }
})


var prvniPolozka = document.querySelector('[data-id="sablona"]');
var sablona = prvniPolozka.cloneNode(true);
var indexPoradi = 2;


function pridatPole() {
  let kopie = sablona.cloneNode(true);
      kopie.querySelector('input.inputPoradi').focus();
      kopie.querySelector('input.inputPoradi').value = indexPoradi;
  prvniPolozka.parentNode.appendChild(kopie);
  indexPoradi++;
}

function odebrat(e) {
  let el = e.target.parentNode;
      el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}
```

```css
[data-id='sablona'] {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1rem
}
```

```html
<div class="polozky row col-12" id="polozky">
  <div class="polozka row col-12 card-footer bg-yellow" data-id="sablona">

    <div class="col-md-1.5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label><input type="hidden" name="policko0[]"></label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1.5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Pořadí: <input type="number" class="inputPoradi" required name="policko1[]" tabindex="1" value=54 min="1"></label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Typ: </label>
        <select class="col-md-7" name="typ[]" data-id="sem" tabindex="3">
          <option selected>Choose...</option>
          <option value="1">Oddělení</option>
          <option value="2">Skupina</option>
          <option value="3">Položka</option>
          <option value="4">Vlastní sleva</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Název:</label>
        <select class="form-select" data-id="Sub1" required>
          <option selected>Choose...</option>
          <option value="sub1">Applied Maths-1</option>
          <option value="sub2">Applied Physics-1</option>
          <option value="sub3">Applied Physics-2</option>

        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button data-id='odebrat' class="XBTN col-md-1 form-group btn btn-block btn-danger odebrat">× Odebrat</button>

    <div class="col-md-1">
      <div class="form-group">
        <button data-id='pridat' class="XBTN btn btn-block btn-success" type="button" tabindex="1">+ Přidat</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```